# Embedding multiple video streams in a single web page

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming, webrtc

I am going to build a live video surveillance system and I wonder if I can implement a browser-based client side application using `html5`, `css` and `javascript`.

The system uses a media server which controls the streams' broadcast, assume the client has a great graphic card, a great network card and a large monitor capable of squeezing multiple videos and no transcoding is needed, `VP8` is the original codec of the streams.

**The system is deployed on a private network.**

The application needs to:

- play a large number of live video streams (around 8 - 16)
- support seeking
- 1080p resolution

My questions are:

- Is it even possible to play that many video streams in a single web page?
- If not, is using a different codec configuration will make the browser capable of playing (like lowering resolution)?
- If not, is there a third party video player which can do that?
- If not, can `electron` handle this job?
- Can WebRtc handle the job?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending 8-16 1080p streams concurrently then bandwidth is going to be a concern (each stream will want about 5000kbps).

Is your source coming from a streaming encoder, or is it a continually growing mp4 file (or similar)? Have you tested accessing it with a single file in the browser?

My recommendation would be to have a streaming encoder that gives you an HLS stream with two bitrates/framesizes (one optimized for the smaller view, one for full screen if you need it)

Comment: It's coming from a hardware encoder, I am sorry I forgot to mention that the system is deployed on a private network

Comment: certainly gives you more bandwidth. have you tried accessing a single feed just using `<video>` tag to the URL? Can the encoder give you HLS, or just the VP8 stream?

Comment: The encoder is transmitting a RTSP stream. The plan is to feed the media server with the RTSP stream, transcode it and broadcast output in WebRtc, I can use HLS instead but this is one of our many planned POCs. Back to my question, is there a proof that a browser can play many HLS stream at once or other streaming protocol?